# Verbo para indicar "bater no cu" (duma criança)?

Tags: expressões, português-europeu, português-brasileiro

Isto pode parecer uma pergunta estúpida ou fora de lugar, mas não é tão assim. Eu falo também italiano, que é a minha segunda lingua, onde existe um termo ou verbo que é "sculacciare" e serve para indicar "o ato de bater no cu (duma criança)". Estava a ver o seguinte video no Youtube

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYFn7aj2UxI&feature=share

onde o rapaz brasileiro parece dizer ao cão (ao segundo 12) algo parecido ao termo/verbo italiano "sculacciare". Visto que sou originario de Portugal e vivi lá só 13 anos, o meu português não é perfeito, mas sobretudo faltam-me algumas expressões, mas mesmo assim não me lembro de pessoas dizerem algum parecido com "sculacciare".

A minha pergunta é a seguinte: existe mesmo um verbo "oficial" para indicar a ação de "bater no cu"? Gostaria de saber se o termo é valido num país ou noutro, ou seja a origem do termo, expressão ou verbo.

Comment: À exceção de *pontapé/chuto no cu*, em Portugal usaríamos a palavra *rabo* e não *cu* (bater com a mão aberta, chinelo, etc.). No Brasil o pessoal tem ainda mais reservas ao uso de *cu* que em Portugal.

Comment: Aqui onde moro no Brasil, falar "bater no cu" é altamente ofensivo

Comment: Não estou a dizer que *cu* é ofensivo. É simplesmente as expressões que me vêm à cabeça: *pontapé no cu, cair de cu, bater com o cu no chão*, mas *palmada no rabo, tau-tau no rabo, chinelada no rabo*. Não me lembro de alguma vez ouvir *palmada no cu* por exemplo.  E imagino que estejas a pensar em palmadas ou chineladas, (pela referência a crianças.) Agora eu sou do sul, pode ser diferente aqui. Onde é que está o ANeves quando a gente precisa dele!

Comment: "Cu" é uma palavra realmente ofensiva no Português Brasileiro,

Comment: A palavra no vídeo é [esculachar](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Ball+of+the+foot), repreender ou espancar, não necessariamente no rabo, e vem realmente do italiano *sculacciare*.

Comment: É interessante ver essa diferença de culturas... Agora no Brasil, o equivalente seria palmadas na bunda/ bater no bumbum (referindo às crianças). Essas expressões acontecem em Portugal?

Comment: Hmm... para mim, no Norte de Portugal, "palmada no rabo" é mais comum e muito mais bem-educado que "palmada no cú", mas a outra também é válida. Uma mãe chateada podia perfeitamente dizer a um filho "é a última vez que te aviso, salta para o banho senão levas tantas palmadas nesse cu que até choras!" E o mesmo para as outras expressões que o @Jacinto comentou ali acima.

Comment: @tdmsoares não, só em tom de brincadeira ou jocoso. Mas percebemo-las perfeitamente.

Comment: @ANeves Também tou a ouvir uma mãe chateada a dizer isso. De resto, embora *cu* não me pareça ofensivo eu evitaria a palavra em situações de alguma cerimónia. Ou então prepararia as pessoas para a palavra com lgum aparato, [como faz este brasileiro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQN5IGq6p8s). Espero que este link teja certo.

Comment: E cá fica o link correto a [esculachar](http://www.aulete.com.br/esculachar) e, já agora, [sculacciàre](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/definizione-lemma.php?definizione=sculacciare&lemma=S0607000)

Comment: @ANeves Nossa! Aqui no Brasil (pelo menos onde estou) rabo é ofensivo... A nâo ser no caso de estar falando de um animal...

Comment: pode ser dito "no rabo" se a mãe já perdeu a paciência, e geralmente usado com chinelada, e não palmadas, PtBR

Comment: @ANeves em Portugal fazer SKI (montanha abaixo) sentando num saco de plástico, é chamado: "SCU"! Junta-se-lhe um "lacciare" e está feito... :)

Answer (score 7):

***Esta resposta é válida no contexto do Português Brasileiro.***

"Sculacciare" se traduz diretamente para o verbo Esculachar, que tem o mesmo significado básico (atingir as nádegas com a mão), apesar de raramente ser utilizado dessa forma.

Esculachar tem um sentido informal e mais comum de atacar alguém verbalmente, e não fisicamente nas regiões das nádegas. O sentido original, literal, hoje quase não é compreendido dessa forma.

De uma forma genérica, podes utilizar o verbo "Surrar" para indicar um castigo físico. Quando aplicado no contexto de "dar uma surra em uma criança", a imagem mental que se vem é algo próximo de *sculacciare*, mas com um intensidade considerável, um castigo severo, por assim dizer.

Podes também utilizar a palavra "estapear", que, assim como "surrar", indica um castigo físico não específico e quando aplicado a um contexto contendo uma criança dá a idéia de um ataque a região das nádegas. Ao contrário de "surrar", "estapear" não carrega uma intensidade explícita e normalmente é aplicado para  um castigo mais brando.

Em uma nota lateral, a palavra "Cu" é um palavrão *extremamente* ofensivo em território brasileiro, possuindo inclusive uma conotação um tanto sexualizada quando em contextos mais brandos. Se possível, evite essa palavra a todo custo quando lidar com interlocutores brasileiros.

Comment: Pelo que eu consigo perceber do italiano, [*sculacciàre*](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/definizione-lemma.php?definizione=sculacciare&lemma=S0607000) significa mesmo bater no rabo com a mão aberta.

Comment: [este dicionário](http://www.sapere.it/sapere/dizionari/dizionari/Italiano/S/SC/sculacciare.html?q_search=sculacci%C3%A0re) diz precisamente que vem de *culo*.

Comment: @Jacinto - Não questiono o significado original da palavra. Creio que não ficou exatamente claro. Vou reformular.

Comment: @Thales Só comentei porque dizes que *sculacciare* se "traduz diretamente" para *esculachar*, mas de acordo com a definição do Aulete de *esculachar*, e a tua também, isso não é verdade.

Comment: @Jacinto A tradução é direta, só não é o formato usual de uso. É como a palavra "Retardado" - Originalmente era um termo médico, mas hoje é uma palavra de cunho pejorativo para uma pessoa de intelecto reduzido. Mesma coisa com "Mongolóide".

Comment: +1 for good answer and good advice.

Answer (score 7):

Eu não conheço nenhum verbo que signifique açoitar alguém no rabo ([*rabo*](http://www.aulete.com.br/rabo) é neste sentido vulgar no Brasil, perfeitamente aceitável em Portugal), com a mão aberta ou de outro modo. E arrisco mesmo que se existir, tal verbo será um regionalismo.

Agora, ***dar palmadas no rabo*** (ptPT) ou ***na bunda*** (ptBR) tem exatamente o significado de *sculacciàre*. Mais ainda, se disseres a uma criança *dou-te uma palmada, levas uma palmada* ou *apanhas uma palmada*, toda a gente vai entender que é o rabo o alvo da palmada. Fica aqui a definição de [***palmada*** no Aulete digital:](http://www.aulete.com.br/palmada)

> **1.** Bras. Golpe dado com a palma da mão, ger[almente] nas nádegas

O Aulete indica *palmada* como brasileirismo, mas não é: é muito comum em Portugal também. Sem mais indicação, pelo menos em Portugal, uma palmada é nas nádegas. Se for noutro lado, é necessário indicar. Por exemplo, uma palmada nas costas, normalmente como saudação ou felicitação. O mesmo golpe de mão aberta mas na cara é uma [*bofetada*](http://www.aulete.com.br/bofetada), e em Portugal também uma [*chapada*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/chapada) ou [*estalada*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/estalada); se for na nuca ou alto da cabeça é em Portugal um [*calduço*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/caldu%C3%A7o).

Comment: Boa resposta! Só acho estranho para mim que sou brasileiro ouvir a expressão "no rabo"...

Comment: @tdmsoares Obrigado pelo aviso. Com estas diferençazinhas uma pessoa nunca sabe quando está a dar um passo em falso. Fiz umas alteraçõezitas na resposta.

Comment: Nunca mais vou comer bacalhau "à Brás" da mesma maneira...

Comment: @bad_coder, essa não estou a alcançar: entre palmadas e bacalhau, a única coisa que me ocorre é bacalhau com batatas a murro.